# Beginner applying ternary operator in Javascript for Pig Latin, but can't figure why it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I'm stuck figuring out why the ternary operator won't return the negative output, and can't really figure out why. Here's the code:

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  let reg=/[aeiou]/gi;
  let firstVowel = str.indexOf(str.match(reg)[0]);
  //console.log(firstVowel);

  return str.match(reg) == 1 ? play(str) : str + "ay";
  
  function play(str) {
    if(str[0].match(reg)){
      return str+"way";
    }else if(str[1].match(reg)){
      return str.slice(1) + str[0]+ "ay"
    } else if(str.match(reg)!==null){
      return str.slice(firstVowel) +str.slice(0,firstVowel)+"ay";
    } else {
      return str+"ay";
    }
}
}
console.log(translatePigLatin("consonant"));
console.log(translatePigLatin("eight"));
console.log(translatePigLatin("glove"));
console.log(translatePigLatin("hmm"));
```

The last test with "hmm" results in error : "TypeError: str.match(...) is null".

I feel better understanding of what null means here could help, but unsure if it makes sense, and how to do so.

How might I better understand this, and make it work? Thanks!

Comment: `String.prototype.match` returns an `Array` or `null`. It does not return a `number` value.

Comment: You should at least tell us what the rules are for forming Pig Latin words.

Answer (score 0):

There is no match for the word "hmm", since there is no vowel with that string. You'll have to conditionalize your function to return a proper result. I updated the code below.

- I took out your else if since you're returning a value in each condition anyway, so it wouldn't read any of the code after returning.
- I didn't see a reason for two encapsulated functions.
- I used template literals as well.

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
   const reg = /[aeiou]/gi;
   const match = str.match(reg);
   const firstVowel = match ? str.indexOf(match[0]) : null;

   if (!firstVowel) {
     return `${str}ay`;
   }

   if (str[0].match(reg)) {
     return `${str}way`;
   }

   if (str[1].match(reg)) {
     return `${str.slice(1)}${str[0]}ay`;
   }

   if (str.match(reg)!== null) {
     return `${str.slice(firstVowel)}${str.slice(0,firstVowel)}ay`;
   }
 };

 console.log(translatePigLatin("consonant"));
 console.log(translatePigLatin("eight"));
 console.log(translatePigLatin("glove"));
 console.log(translatePigLatin("hmm"));
```

Comment: You may also want to check whether a string is actually the parameter ```if (!str && typeof str !== 'string') return null;```